# Suggest the steps for "Author Identfication"?

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I have one project in that I want to indentify the author of given text, blogs for that 
how to create training data and corpus for specific author?

Please suggest some links and also algorithm for the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is too broad to be answered well on this site. As described in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Answer (score 4):

There are many approaches to the task of authorship identification.  Since it seems like you're new in NLP, I would suggest starting with a basic, bag-of-words-vector approach:

1. Come up with a set of words that will serve as features.
2. Take each document and convert it to a vector of counts for each of the feature words.
3. Cluster the vectors by cosine similarity.
4. Documents that end up in the same cluster are likely to be written by the same author.

Now there's one important catch that makes clustering for authorship identification different from normal document clustering: In normal document clustering we try to ignore "stopwords", the high-frequency words like "the", "be", "that", etc and just focus on "content words".  But in authorship identification, it turns out that those stopwords are the things that make an individual's writing unique!  So the vectors should actually be clustered according to how the author uses these function words in the writing.

As a next step, try using coming up with better features such as word bigrams, since those will give a little better insight into the unique aspects of the author's writing style.

For a wide view of the area and the techniques that people have tried, check out what [Google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=authorship+identification) has to say.  You should probably look for survey articles or other papers that give an overview of the field so you can get a good idea of what people have tried and what has been successful.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.Now i will try for suggested thing and revert if any issue regarding the same.Thank you so much again .

Answer (score 1):

You could use neural networks. There is an article [here](http://home.southernct.edu/~pasqualonia1/sonnet/report.html) for example, that tries to identify authors of works by Shakespeare, Fletcher, and Marlowe. It also includes some python scripts (and neural networks implementation in C). And also some data files that should give you an idea how to compose your training data.

But as stated before, for now your question remains overly broad. Hopefully this example can get you started, so you can come back and ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving approch.Now i will try for that and ask the more specific question so its more clear for the team also and me also.Thank you again.